# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. Installing etkinlik.io composer

Tags: php, api

While installing etkinlik.io composer, I encountered an error like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25fy6.png)

What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: How do you do the install steps and what's the output info?

Comment: I was missing my composer setup. I think I fixed the deficiency but now I am facing another problem.